# How to add a Currency Symbol in SQL Server Results?

Tags: sql, sql-server, character-encoding, ssms

I currently have the following

SELECT "£" [Currency_code]

which returns

| Currency_code |
| --- |
| £ |

I am happy with that outcome, but when I export the script to .csv format the "£" shows as an "?"

how can I get it so that it shows as the "£" in the export?

thank you in advance

Comment: What do you mean export the script to CSV? Though the reason would be because you're saving the file using a code page where the Pound Character (`£`) isn't represented.

Comment: Also, however, `SELECT "£" [Currency_code]` wouldn't return the dataset you say; it's more likely to return the error *"Invalid column name '£'."*

Comment: If `set quoted_identifier off` then it will return that result but you shouldn't use that

Comment: You should not force the currency symbol, instead you could use the `FORMAT` function, as shown [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/7023/sql-format-currency-options/)

Comment: In any event you have asked us a question about issues "when I export the script to .csv format" and told us nothing about what process you are currently using to do that

Comment: sorry @MartinSmith , my SQL Server script is sent to Powershell and there it is converted into a CSV file. i have noticed when i open my results into a spreadsheet the £ shows as a ?, but when i manually change the ? to a £ in the spreadsheet it works. i hope that makes sense. thank you for you help so far!

Comment: So you need to show the code you are using to do that